# I'm running Apache 2.4.7, but my .htaccess files are only working with pre-2.4 directives & syntax

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, htaccess

I've been dealing with a pretty unusual issue all day.

My remote server is running Apache version is 2.4.7

However, when I start setting up directives in the .htaccess files such as this:

```
<RequireAny>
  Require ip 188.81.144.30
</RequireAny>
```

none of the Apache 2.4 directives work. In fact, I get bad server config status codes '500'.

However, when I use the old, pre-2.4 directives such as this:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
allow from 188.81.144.30
```

it works flawlessly.

Is it possible that either mod_authz_host or mod_access_compat or both aren't working correctly? Is there any way to check this without root privs?

I've been dealing with this all day. Everything I've tried has failed. I have no idea what to even consider. It's like looking outside to a clear, warm summer evening, then you open your front door and a blizzard is roaring at 110%. It's complete nonsense to me right now.

Thanks in advance to anybody who either knows what's going on or can help me figure out which of the two mod files (if any) is gumming everything up.